# calling menu from custom button in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, optionmenu

I would like to call my menu from a custom button :

With targetversion<=10 this works fine with calling openOptionsMenu from onClick-Method of the button:

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

From targetversion>=11 this doesn't work.

Also to mention. With <=10 the Menuitem appears at the bottom:

[image]

With >=11 this icon disappeared.

Background :
I like to have a targetversion=16.
My app hides the TitleBar and Optionmenu appears in the Titlebar in Jelly Bean.
Because of this I want to get rid of the google UI's changes every release, which costs a lot of developing/testing efforts every time. So I thought to have my own button which is GoogleApi independent.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions ?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling `openOptionsMenu()` from an Activity? SDK [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) still mentions it as an active API. I double checked with `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` and works just perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just verify this... and tell you :-)

Comment: This didn't work for me with android:targetSdkVersion="16". With 10 its working. Also the menubutton appears at the bottom with "10"

Comment: Thats, _Are you sure you are calling openOptionsMenu() from an Activity?_

Comment: Menu button appearing at the bottom is just fine, that's due to backward compatibility.

Comment: Hmmm you are right I am calling it from a custom View with the method onSingleTapUp(). Sorry for the cunfusion. I though this would be the same, because it works for <="10". Could that be a difference ? So how could I do that from my custom view with a touch event ?

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without the actual source code, but maybe you can have a public method in your main activity (which will call `openOptionsMenu()`) and call it from your custom view class on touch event?

Comment: I will try this, thank you. By the way I guess I am thinking about creating my own menu in my custom view. I guess it will look better and I get rid of the menu-mechanism of google which changes in any api-release :-) . Thanks a lot. Anyway I could accept your answer, because it is working on your side. What do you think ?

Comment: _Anyway I could accept your answer, because it is working on your side. What do you think?_ --- Well, that's a decision to make wholly at your discretion :)